# How can I change the template loaded when created a new Shiny App in RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been using RStudio to create Shiny apps. When creating a new one-file Shiny app via the "New..." button in RStudio, the following code is automatically loaded:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My first step of app creation is to delete the bodies of `fluidPage` and the server function. What I really want is an essentially blank template:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I change the default template used to create new Shiny Apps? I'm shocked that I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere online, so if someone could point me towards an existing answer I would be very grateful.

I actually don't care to ever make the app RStudio uses as a template (which is the `01_hello_world` example that comes with Shiny) so if anyone could tell me where the new App template is stored, I can just edit that.

Just some notes on things I've already tried:

1. Changing the script `shiny/examples/01_hello_world/app.R` to the "blank" one.
2. looking in the `shiny/template` folder; this contains only an HTML document.
3. adding an `app.R` file containing my desired script to `shiny/template`.

I'll add that I'm running RStudio on Debian Linux. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found the files just after posting this. At least on Debian, they are stored in /usr/lib/rstudio-server/resources/templates/shiny. One must have root access to edit these. I have no idea if there's some way to point RStudio towards a custom script stored in one's home directory, and would still be interested to learn a less dramatic solution.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_project_templates.html (or at least useful).